# Is it possible to reference individual tabs of a QTabWidget by tab number?

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

Very quick question here. I was wondering if it is possible for me to reference individual tabs from a QTabWidget by number. This will save me a lot of time, as I am generating an unknown number of tabs during run-time. I could not find anything in the QT documentation, but I feel like this is a very basic feature that should be included. I am thinking something like this (not real code just an idea, I realize tabNumber() doesn't exist):

```
 ui->tabArea->tabNumber(12);
```

If there isn't a public function, perhaps there's some other way? Please don't suggest referencing tabs by name because that is out of the question (potentially 100's of tabs), and I have already tried it.

Comment: How can a UI with "hundreds of tabs" ever be usable?

Comment: I am using it to generate a geometric domain for block-mesh input into a computational fluid dynamics program. It is VERY unlikely there will ever be more than 25 tabs, I guess I was just exaggerating, but you never know what kind of crazy stuff us engineers will need! :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the tab with a certain index, use widget():

```
 QWidget* tab = tabWidget->widget( index );
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I knew there was a simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `setCurrentIndex()` method is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm unsure how I would use this to actually reference the tab number. I want to create an array of check boxes in each tab using: new QCheckBox( ui->checkBoxAreaTab->tabNumber( k ) ). How would I actually pass the tab I want to the constructor by number? (k is a variable)